# The output (while it is by all means correct programmingly) gives a weird square output (I've attached picture aswell)

Tags: assembly, mips

Don't worry you do not have to check the whole program but only **caseThree**. I have debugged the program (with whatever knowledge I have) and the problem is when the program comes back from **caseThree** and goes to **while_mn** again and tries to print the **option_prompt** I get the following output: [Mars 4.5 output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxDLa.jpg) (I am talking about the weird square not the numbers) and then it stops working. This assignment is for tomorrow and i'm honestly baffled with what's happening. You guys are my last resort because i've spent 2 hours trying to look what the problem is and i've had no progress. (You don't have to waste time on the function of the program since i'm certain at this point that something goes wrong with the $v0). Thanks a lot in advance, honestly!

```
   .data
    .align 2
        int_array_1: .space 20
        int_array_2: .space 20
        option_prompt: .asciiz "Give me an option between 1-5: "
        valid_number: .asciiz "Give me a valid number please!!!!\n"
        n_prompt: .asciiz "Give me the number N: "
        space: .asciiz " "
        newline: .asciiz "\n"
        is_even_message: .asciiz "The number is even\n"
        is_odd_message: .asciiz "The number is odd\n"   
        give_number_for_array: .asciiz "Give number for array: "

    .text
        main:
            while_mn:
                #print option prompt
                li $v0, 4
                la $a0, option_prompt
                syscall

                #get integer option
                li $v0, 5
                syscall

                #store the option in $t0
                move $t0, $v0

                #jump to cases
                beq $t0, 1, caseOne
                beq $t0, 2, caseTwo
                beq $t0, 3, caseThree
                beq $t0, 4, caseFour
                beq $t0, 5, caseFive

                #print valid number message
                li $v0, 4
                la $a0, valid_number
                syscall

                j while_mn
            exit_while_mn:

            li $v0, 10
            syscall

        caseOne:
            #print n prompt
            li $v0, 4
            la $a0, n_prompt
            syscall

            #get N number
            li $v0, 5
            syscall

            #store the number N in $t1
            move $t1, $v0

            #set $t2=i to 1
            addi $t2, $zero, 1

            for_columns:
                bgt $t2, $t1, exit_for_columns

                #t3=k=1
                addi $t3, $zero, 1

                for_rows:
                    bgt $t3, $t2, exit_for_rows

                    #print k
                    li $v0, 1
                    la $a0, ($t3)
                    syscall

                    #print space
                    li $v0, 4
                    la $a0, space
                    syscall

                    #k+=1
                    addi $t3, $t3, 1

                    j for_rows

                exit_for_rows:

                #print newline
                li $v0, 4
                la $a0, newline
                syscall

                #i+=1
                addi $t2, $t2, 1
                j for_columns
            exit_for_columns:

            j while_mn
        caseTwo:
            #print n prompt
            li $v0, 4
            la $a0, n_prompt
            syscall

            #get N number
            li $v0, 5
            syscall

            #store the number N in $t1
            move $t1, $v0  

            #t2=0
            addi $t2, $zero, 0

            while_smaller:
                bge $t2, $t1, exit_while_smaller
                addi $t2, $t2, 2
                j while_smaller
            exit_while_smaller:

            beq $t1, $t2, is_even

            #print is_odd
            li $v0, 4
            la $a0, is_odd_message
            syscall

            j while_mn

            is_even:
                #print is_even
                li $v0, 4
                la $a0, is_even_message
                syscall
                j while_mn
        caseThree:
            addi $t1, $zero, 20

            #the index
            addi $t3, $zero, 0

            while_fill_1:
                beq $t3, $t1, exit_while_fill_1

                #print give number
                li $v0, 4
                la $a0, give_number_for_array
                syscall

                #get number
                li $v0, 5
                syscall

                move $s1, $v0

                sw $s1, int_array_1($t3)

                #index+=4
                addi $t3, $t3, 4

                j while_fill_1

            exit_while_fill_1:

            #the index
            addi $t6, $zero, 0

            while_fill_2:
                beq $t6, $t1, exit_while_fill_2

                lw $s5, int_array_1($t6)
                addi $s5, $s5, 0

                #t5 = t4*2^2=t4*4
                sll $t5, $s5, 2

                sw $t5, int_array_2($t3)

                li $v0, 1
                la $a0, ($t5)

                syscall

                #print space
                li $v0, 4
                la $a0, space
                syscall

                #index+=4
                addi $t6, $t6, 4

                j while_fill_2
            exit_while_fill_2:

            j while_mn
        caseFour:
            j while_mn
        caseFive:
            j exit_while_mn
```

Comment: I would recommend writing your algorithm in a higher-level language first, then converting it to assembly afterwards. C is a good choice, since it can be mapped to assembly very directly (also, if you get stuck, you can consult an actual compiler and compare).

Comment: That probably means you have overwritten your `option_prompt`. Check that in the simulator.

Comment: The line `sw $t5, int_array_2($t3)` should probably use `$t6` not `$t3` as that was for the previous loop and is already `20`. That is why you are overwriting memory.

Comment: @Jester I honestly love you! Sorry for this idiotic question as it turned out i'm just stupid with no eyes. Thanks a lot man <3